# Old SQL installation media

Tags: sql-server, licensing

We have `MSSQL Server 2008 R2` licenses. We have an Action Pack subscription, which provides us `SQL 2014`. But we just need the installation media for `2008 R2` so that we can install Reporting Services. We are not prepared today to urgently upgrade our MSSQL, so the download that Microsoft provides is not helpful.

Is there any place to go for downloading older versions of MS software like this? We have the license keys. Somebody else did the installation though, so it's not like we have (or really ever had the actual install discs). This would probably be helpful for other software, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to sign into your MSDN account and then visit:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/

You should see all the software you have the right to download listed there.

If you can't do this, you can also download ISO copies of the media from P2P sharing sites but I would be hesitant to do this since it may be hard to verify the integrity of the files within.

Worst case scenario, call Microsoft and see what they can do for you.